# How to filter data after particular date in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to filter the data between the dates. I have used `WhereBetween` but it is not working.

[image: table data]

Here is my code

```
  $from = Carbon::parse($req->start_date_of_registration);
            $to = Carbon::parse($req->end_date_of_registration);
            $data = tbl_company::whereBetween(
                "date_of_registration",
                [
                    $from,
                    $to
                ]
            )
                ->paginate(100);
```

Comment: whats the format of date_of_registration value and start_date_of_registration

Comment: `12-08-2022` => comes from the request and I have set datatype string in the database

Comment: Why you don't use carbon for parsing and formatting instead... eg: Carbon\Carbon::parse('12-08-2022')

Comment: Okay i will try with it sir.

Comment: it is not filtering though sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[whereDate](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries)  works only if database table column data type is `timestamp` or `datetime` or  `date` .Since you are storing `date` as `varchar` (example value in date_of_registration column is  `12-08-2022`) ,you have to use raw query like below

```
 $data = tbl_company::whereBetween(
        DB::Raw("STR_TO_DATE(date_of_registration,'%d-%m-%Y')"), [ $from,$to])
        ->paginate(100);
```

Comment: Not working sir. though your explanation is helpful.

Comment: @swapnilmane can you tell me the value in date_of_registration in database which format date is storing.better if you add table data screenshot

Comment: Okay sir. and i have also added image.

Comment: @swapnilmane  check the updated answer and try.it should work

Comment: It's working. Your code is working perfectly sir. Thank you so much. I know these comments are not allowed but you deserve it. You have solved my problem and it will help others as well who are facing such kind of date filtering issues.

Comment: please take a look at this question sir. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73342766/call-to-a-member-function-links-on-array-in-laravel-8-with-pagination

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
$start_date = Carbon::parse($request->start_date)->toDateTimeString();

$end_date = Carbon::parse($request->end_date)->toDateTimeString();

User::whereBetween('created_at', [
         $start_date,
         $end_date
      ])->get();
```

Comment: NOt working sir

Answer (score 0):

send date as string format (Y-m-d) `1997-04-30`

**or** use strtotime to formate date

```
$data = tbl_company::whereBetween(
            "date_of_registration",
            [
                date('Y-m-d',strtotime($from)),
                date('Y-m-d',strtotime($to))
            ]
        )
            ->paginate(100);
```