# Call to a member function links() on array in laravel 8 with pagination

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, pagination

I am getting this error while paginating from one page to another page.
when I click on the 2 number link following error occurs.

**Call to a member function links() on array**
**FUNCTION**

```
 $data = tbl_company::query()
                ->where(
                    "company_name",
                    "LIKE",
                    "%{$req->company_name}%"
                )->paginate(100);
            return view('/admin/company/index', compact('data', 'showPagination'));
```

**BLADE.FILE**

```
 {{$data->links()}}
```

Comment: What did you mean by links()?

Comment: links() display the pagination in the laravel blade file.

Comment: Okay, you just dump and die $data. Then you will understand what kind of data is in the $data

Comment: use bootstrap or vuejs ?

Answer (score 2):

In the controller, append the query data that you need (not the whole request object)

```
 $data = tbl_company::query()
                ->where(
                    "company_name",
                    "LIKE",
                    "%{$req->company_name}%"
                )
                ->paginate(100)
                ->withQueryString();

            return view('/admin/company/index', compact('data', 'showPagination'));
```

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/pagination#appending-query-string-values

Comment: And please consider using conventions for class names

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
{!! $data->render() !!}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73350259/filter-data-between-dates-along-with-multiple-search-queries-in-laravel

Answer (score 0):

I solved this question after modifying blade file

I changed code

**from**

```
{{$data->links()}}
```

**to**

```
 {!! $data->appends(Request::all())->links() !!}
```

Comment: don't use raw`{!! !!}` unless you really know what you are doing.  You can also append in the controller making the original blade code work